# Spatial index not speeding up spatialite query containing Multipoint Geometry Data?

Tags: coordinates, spatialite, spatial-index

I am querying a sqlite format geodatabase in which there is a label for each geometry shape.

Think of data as :

```
label = name of a district in your state 

geometry: polygon which specify the boundary of that district.
```

Now, I have coordinates of a person and I want to find out in which state he resides. The problem is that there are around 170 thousand districts and running my query for each input i.e. coordiantes takes around 7 seconds. After reading other articles, I tried spatial index but the results are same. It still takes around the same time. I guess I am not using it properly. I need a bit of advice on how can I improve the query time.

Code involved [Python 3.5]:

```
voting_district_conn= sqlite3.connect('Voting_Districts.sqlite')
voting_district_conn.enable_load_extension(True)
voting_district_conn.execute("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')")
...
index_cursor = voting_district_conn.execute("SELECT CreateSpatialIndex('voting_districts','GEOMETRY')")
for item in index_cursor:
print(item)  #returning (0,)
...
start_time = time.time()
voting_district_cursor = voting_district_conn.execute("SELECT label from voting_districts where within(GeomFromText('POINT("+lng+" "+lat+")'),GeomFromWKB(GEOMETRY))")
for item in voting_district_cursor:
    print(item)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Spatial index in SpatiaLite does not work transparently as in PostGIS. You must utilize spatial index table in a subquery or in a join. There are examples in this blog https://erouault.blogspot.com/2017/03/dealing-with-huge-vector-geopackage.html. But I do not understand your idea about using multipoint for specifying the boundary of a district. Why not polygon?

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for your advice and it is a polygon. I will edit the question. Extending to your advice, I found this [blog] (http://blog.jrg.com.br/2016/05/23/Querying-spatial-data-using-spatialite-with-indexes/) which helped me to understand it.

Comment: Yes, search frame is a convenience in SpatiaLite that makes it easier to write the queries.

Comment: @user30184 However, running the query I found out that SpatialIndex was never created in the first place.  The index_cursor is returning 0 and the resources I found till now don't give a reason as to when CreateSpatialIndex query could fail.